# replication slave has less space

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication, database-administration, master-slave

I need to setup the replication

so for that i took backup from the master and imported into slave  and now slave has 20 GB free space,
at the time while i am restoring backup master got 5+ GB of data

after that i enabled replication

Now the problem is while data from the relay log is written to slave many new relay logs are generated and i am left with no space on slave....

The **relay-log-purge**  is enabled but the writing process from relay log to database is very slow...

Comment: What type of binlogs do you use? Statement or row based?

Answer (score 1):

You may have performance benefits by switching binlog format to 'ROW'. In mixed format mysql is writing binlog statement based (the slave has to reparse and plan the strategy again) and only switches to row format in certain cases (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-log-mixed.html).

It can be done on the fly:

```
SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'ROW';
```

With ROW based replication you can offload the slaves which makes them easier to keep up with the master. The only downside of it is you may have larger log files however from this "got 5+ GB of data" I assume you mainly do inserts so the there will be no difference.

Best is to try it and see how it behaves.

Other option until the replication catches up to change the innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit to 2 on the slave. Only do this temporary.

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2;
```

Comment: problem is with the slave i think there is no relation with the master binlog format check it out once

Answer (score 0):

just turn off the slave io thread when you get less disk space alert (90% reached) as

```
mysql> stop slave io_thread;
```

and start it again after some time as

```
mysql> start slave io_thread;
```

on production this is the only best possible option......

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your config

relay-log-space-limit=5G